# How to automatically fetch updated data from database when session has already started

Tags: php, html

Please I'm a beginner in web developments so I created a simple login system that leads to dashboard.
But when I'm logged in and I make some changes in the database or normal settings, it doesn't reflect the changes until I  re-login.
How do I make changes reflect immediately?

I tried updating the session, but when I re-login, I won't be able to get the previous echo from the session

```
<?php

session_start();
$_SESSION['name']=$name;
$_SESSION['number']=$number;

?>
<?php
    echo "Your name is: ".$name."<br/>";
    echo "User id is: ".$number;
?>
```

And when I use the database sessions I won't be able to receive update until I re-login.

```
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['userdata'])) {
    $user = $_SESSION['userdata'][0];
}else{
  header("Location: login.php");
}
?>
<h2>Your name is <?=$user['name']?></h2>
```

Please can anyone help?

Comment: after you update the database you update any session variables required and reload the page (to see changed values f written to page as above). There should be no need to login again - please add the code that updates db &/or what you tried before

Comment: Please can you do some code samples?

Comment: if you know how to update the db and how to update the session, you already know how to do this -- you just do *both* instead of only doing one of them.